# Pie chart legend shows empty values

Tags: highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Using dot net highcharts and the label formatter to only display certain items in the legend, it displays values that have been returned as ''.

```
.SetLegend(new Legend { Enabled = true, LabelFormatter = "function() { if (this.y >= 5) { return this.name; } else { return ''; } }"  })
```

[image: Legend display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable default legend and create your own as HTML. Then you can control which point should be or not displayed.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/

```
$legend = $('#customLegend');

    $.each(chart.series[0].data, function (j, data) {

        $legend.append('<div class="item"><div class="symbol" style="background-color:'+data.color+'"></div><div class="serieName" id="">' + data.name + '</div></div>');

    });

    $('#customLegend .item').click(function(){
        var inx = $(this).index(),
            point = chart.series[0].data[inx];

        if(point.visible)
            point.setVisible(false);
        else
            point.setVisible(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The formatter only formats the text that gets displayed - it does not determine whether or not there is a legend entry for a series.

What you need is the `showInLegend` property, and you will need to run your check on the series object, not on the legend.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.showInLegend

Comment: This works if you have multiple series, but for the pie chart you have one series with multiple points. Therefore I cannot run the check on each series..